# how to compare 2 digits number in array

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program to find duplictate number in array. The following program is working when number are single digits but for double digit number it is not working

```
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
  num = nums.sort()
  if (num.length === 0) {
    return false
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      if (num[i] == num[i + 1]) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in your last iteration step you compare out of bounds value

Comment: Please, provide also input and expected output data

Comment: you can take any 2 digit number

Comment: I don't see why this would care how many digits are in the numbers.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work for single-digit numbers too. Try to pass `[1,4,7,5,2,4,6,7]` (`4` and `7` are defined twice in this array), but the function returns `false`.

Comment: Your function returns immediatelhy on the first iteration. So it's just comparing the first two numbers in the sorted array, not all the numbers.

Comment: because you immediately return false after the first comparison

Comment: `return false` should be outside the loop.

Comment: i have found the error return false should be outsite loop

Answer (score 0):

First update your condition to num.length-1 to not run out of boundaries. Second return true if there is a duplicate but don't return false inside the else block.
When no duplicate was found then return false at the end of the function.

```js
function containsDuplicate(nums) {
  num = nums.sort()
  if (num.length === 0) {
    return false
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length-1; i++) {
      if (num[i] === num[i + 1]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(containsDuplicate([2,3,4,4,5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates, you can proceed in the following way:

```
let a = (x) => {return Array.from(new Set(x))};

a([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,11,9,8,10,11,12]);
```

Expected output:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

Hope that it is what you wanted.